# Can we run a program without os?

Tags: operating-systems

Because os is a special kind of program so does that also mean a normal program can run without os ?

Comment: Also the program is boot up as os ( but it is not os ) and don't use any api

Comment: What do you mean by "normal program"?

Comment: I don't understand how this question is any different from the one you asked yesterday.

Comment: No this is about run program without os not an os without api

Comment: 1) Yes, if the program is an OS.  2)  Yes, if you have some way of getting the program into the memory of a computer without an OS.  (And yes, it is possible.)